# Como será tratada uma "guerra de votos" ou "serial downvote" no br.SO?

Tags: suporte, comportamento, votação

No [SO original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting/28758#28758) eu já havia lido há alguns meses que um *serial downvote* pode ocorrer, mas ele é revertido automaticamente pelo sistema.

Minha dúvida é: isso se aplica também ao br.SO? O sistema irá reverter isso automaticamente ou devemos denunciar para que um moderador tome as devidas providências?

---

Motivo da pergunta: pois é... isso aconteceu comigo hoje após um desentendimento com um outro usuário por causa de *down votes* (é só conferir pelo horário):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coincidência ou não, olha o e-mail que recebi no mesmo horário em meu blog (que está no meu perfil do SO):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E pessoal, por favor, se alguém achar que eu me excedi ou fui injusto em algum comentário, por favor me dê um toque para eu editar ou apagar o item.

Comment: Se eu fosse moderador, eu daria a honra a esse seu camarada de receber o primeiro ban do stackoverflow em português.

Comment: O votos negativos provavelmente serão cancelados nessa madrugada. Não sei como está a heurística do algoritmo de detecção, mas acho que já disparou o script. Avise amanhã se não acontecer. Não vou responder porque acho que só a equipe pode dar uma resposta com autoridade. Adianto que essa situação específica já está sendo analisada. O que posso observar é que atitudes imaturas que ataquem outros membros de uma forma ou de outra não podem ser toleradas. Será que é possível atribuir origem/autoria da mensagem de e-mail mostrada?

Comment: Não sou advogado, mas se essa pessoa continuar a atacar sua pessoa, isso tem uma boa probabilidade de constituir um crime no Brasil.

Comment: Detalhe que o IP do e-mail é de Londrina.

Comment: Fiquei seriamente decepcionado com essa atitude.

Comment: Uau, o título do email devia ter sido "Eu vou me arrepender", nerd burro mesmo :) - Relacionada: [*What do I do about receiving an offensive email from another user on Stack Overflow?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261941/1287812)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Como o StackOverflow em Português usa a mesma *engine* dos demais sites da rede StackExchange, supõe-se que ele possua os mesmos mecanismos automatizados, seja de detecção de fraude de votos ou com outros propósitos. Não creio que sites específicos tenham comportamentos específicos, mas como disse @bigown, somente a equipe do SE pode dar uma resposta definitiva.

E como de costume, se acreditar que uma intervenção humana seja necessária, basta sinalizar como "outro (precisa da ♦ atenção do moderador)". (nesse caso não é necessário marcar **todos** os *posts*  (perguntas/respostas) problemáticos, apenas escolha um deles e descreva sua situação.)

A propósito, seus votos contrários sofridos já foram revertidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A situação já está sendo analisada pela moderação desde ontem.

Comment: O sistema de detecção de votos fraudulentos é o mesmo para todos os sites da rede e **obviamente** ninguém pode entrar em detalhes de como ele funciona. Providências já foram tomadas sobre essa e outras atitudes reprováveis