# Constatação de votos de perseguição?

Tags: debate

Bem estou aqui só para avisar e de certa forma mostrar em anexo figura a perseguição tirando votos sem nenhuma justificativa (perseguição porque os votos são em sequencia e no mesmo dia e praticamente minutos):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a minha indignação é o fato da rede estar num momento ruim e tentarmos de várias formas ajudar e percebo que parece (suposição) que muitos torcem contra, dão votam de qualquer jeito e não avaliam de maneira correta as respostas. Eu sei bem que não é obrigação de deixar uma mensagem do problema na resposta, mas, isso seria muito bom.

Esses votos não vão mudar nada em minha vida, só queria mesmo deixar registrado essa condução desse determinado usuário.

<sup>***Link***: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/54880/virgilio-novic?tab=reputation</sup>

Comment: Acho que seria bom a moderação verificar se o emissor dos votos é de um mesmo usuário ou contas fantoches(usuários diferente com o mesmo ip) pois os intervalos dos votos são muito próximos e eu vi as questões e as respostas não permitem uma análise tão rápida. Se for o caso de manipulação de votos acho que certo é reverter e aplicar uma sanção. Agora se os votos vierem de usuários diferentes e não relacionados se trata apenas de infeliz coincidência. Não sei se seria o tramite correto você mesmo sinalizar para a moderação as três respostas como suspeita de manipulação visando o prejudicar.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu acho quase certeza que é o mesmo usuário, mas, várias vezes eu fiz sinalizações aos moderadores e não houve êxito nenhum só textos padrões vindo na minha área de usuário.

Comment: Vale lembrar que duas das perguntas que você respondeu já estão negativadas e também uma esta fechada, pode parecer injusto e já passei por isso também, mas as vezes perguntas ruins do quais tem respostas com caracteristica de apenas suporte técnico (causado pela pergunta e não pela resposta) acabam por receber downvotes, obviamente que não seria um ataque/perseguição nesse caso, mas como os votos foram em sequencia indica que é sim... passei o mesmo com um usuário que tem mais de 40k, que começou a me negativar e a SO até hoje nada pois geralmente só com formulário do site para resolver..

Comment: ... Por fim o que lhe sugiro é que se você tem o suspeito em mente coloque o perfil dele na sinalização e também use o formulário https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact, já vou lhe adiantar, recuperar os votos nas postagens é quase improvavel, mas ao menos penalizar o perseguidor é algo que talvez consiga. PS: no meu caso o perseguidor continua livre, leve e solto, pois ele foi me perseguir em outro site da  rede.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento quando eu respondi as questões não tinham votos negativos e também de certo modo não vejo problemas nisso, pode chegar qualquer moderador e fechar a questão (isso está ficando raro aqui, e eu entendo o motivo, não estou culpando, só constatando). o grande problema é a perseguição isso não deve acontecer principalmente com nós que ainda ajudamos a rede (não é tratamento especial já vou também alertar) e as respostas estão corretas, não há problemas nelas e foi sim perseguição na minha humilde visão.

Comment: ...  Sinceridade todas as vezes que alguém coloca uma pergunta da tag `javascript` automaticamente parece um robo a pergunta leva negativo. @GuilhermeNascimento mas, a gente sabe que a rede está com problemas, eu não sei quem seria o engraçadinho que anda fazendo isso, não tem como saber, mas, é como também relatei a minha vida não vai mudar por causas desses votos negativos, mas, queria que todos soubessem para não passar a mesma situação. Obrigado Guilherme

Comment: Bem, essa questão da tag javascript (e CSS também, se você notou) é que tem aparecido muita pergunta mal elaborada e dificil de reproduzir, ou que é apenas "erro de digitação" e só serve ao autor da pergunta, agora se acredita que tem algumas que se salvam é algo que pode ser debatido a parte aqui no meta, mas sobre isso eu nem discuto mais, é algo que já foi tão debatido no Meta e chat que se tornou cansativo. De qualquer forma sobre a perseguição, que do meu ponto de vista parece ser perseguição mesmo, é sinalizar se tiver o perfil de quem suspeita e usar o formulário.

Comment: é verdade sobre `javascript` e `css` as perguntas de certo modo são de baixa qualidade, e a gente tenta salvar é isso que eu tento fazer, estou vendo um moderador saindo de cena porque o SE não auxilia tanto como deveria, a gente fica também a merce disso tudo eu gosto de ajudar entendeu e dessas 3 perguntas talvez uma seja questionável ... mas, tudo bem fazer o que, eu estou tentando ajudar mesmo ... @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Eu pessoalmente nunca percebi isso, o que a pessoa ganha com retaliar outra dessa forma ? Ambos perdem pontos, qual o objetivo ? É coisa que não entra na minha cabeça

Comment: @Isac, é mesma lógica do viciado suicida, vou morrer de overdose porém antes arrastarei alguém comigo.

Comment: @Isac recebi outro voto negativo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/471742/usestate-n%c3%a3o-funciona-como-o-esperado/471750#471750 é pura perseguição

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento recebi outro voto negativo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/471742/usestate-n%c3%a3o-funciona-como-o-esperado/471750#471750 é pura perseguição

Comment: @AugustoVasques recebi outro voto negativo pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/471742/… é pura perseguição

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sinalize ao moderadores e nada aconteceu !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu não disse que seria do dia para noite, ou no dia seguinte, eu sinalizei o tal individuo que me perseguiu por mais de um mês, levou quase 4 meses para eu receber um feedback dos moderadores, fora que no final só me orientaram a usar o tal formulário que eu citei, claro que o tal sujeito que me perseguiu veio do SOpt, mas ele me perseguiu em outros sites da rede, então usei o formulário de outros sites `/contact`, e de resto só estou tendo paciência, não é fácil.

Comment: eu usei o formulário @GuilhermeNascimento, fazer o que neh a gente está tentando ... obrigado.

Comment: A outra resposta também tomou negativo.

Comment: Sim ela tomou bem antes da minha @AugustoVasques ! e a outra tomou positivo e negativo, estranho, eu tenho como provar que a minha resposta é a unica correta, não querendo me gabar não é isso ... !

Comment: Eu fiz o que estava ao meu alcance,  [sinalizei](https://imgur.com/a/h3RfnOB) o negativo que recebeu.

Comment: PS: Eu positivei as duas respostas objetivando neutralizar os dois negativos.

Comment: Sim sim, eu só gostaria mesmo que isso parasse, essa perseguição parece que não tem fim! não é o voto em si agradeço seu voto, mas, veja, isso é chato de mais @AugustoVasques

Comment: Caro @Isac desculpe, demorei a notar o seu comentário, então, eu creio que existam 2 motivos para esses downvotes em série, o primeiro é realmente atacar, simplesmente porque as pessoas que fazem isso olham o score e não a qualidade da postagem, pois querem de fato prejudicar nem que seja minimamente e mesmo também perdendo score... O outro motivo, e que acho que foi o caso do meu perseguidor, era fazer que minhas respostas parecessem ruins, ele tinha mais de 40k, então quando me negativava ele não sentia a perda, mas minhas postagens pareciam conter um problema, que não existia.

Answer (score 11):

De fato esses 3 votos é de alguém revoltado, mas nem dá para moderação fazer algo. Só para ter uma ideia isso acontece com moderadores o tempo todo e não dá para fazer nada dentro dos critérios da SE.

Para dar um exemplo tinha uma pessoa que tinha uma conta e causava vários problemas, e dava votos negativos desse jeito, até pior. De tanto estrago a pessoa abandonou a conta e criou outra, e foi fazendo isso várias vezes, até que estabilizou em uma conta. Parou de negativar por vingança? Não, mas não fez mais de jeito que desse para fazer algo. Só para ter uma ideia como ainda faz a única pessoa que esse usuário negativa é um moderador que ele demonstra não gostar, até por ser um moderador que "sempre" dá notícia ruim para ele. Então você vê que o padrão de voto (negativos e falta de positivos (que é diferente de todo mundo que ele faz com outros usuários) é tendencioso, e mesmo assim nessa conta não houve punição, embora ficou bem próximo disso, mais um pouco e pode rolar. É muito claro que a pessoa não negativa desse jeito outras pessoas. Dá para ver com clareza a tendência, ela só não foi tão grande ainda.

O que estou querendo dizer? Que esse é um caso muito pequeno para tomar uma providência. É assim com todos usuários. Mas se fosse um pouco mais, seria o caso de fazer algo. Eu até faria por mim, mas não é muito o critério da SE. Para fazer nesse teria que fazer em outros casos também. Também estou dizendo que esse caso tem mais especulação do que o caso que contei antes, que tem uma situação mais óbvia de perseguição.

A pessoa deu 3 votos, não mais que isso. Outros negativos foram dados por outros pessoas. Ninguém negativou o AP maciçamente, todos usuários dando menos 10 negativos nele, e tirando 2 usuários todos os outros deram menos de 5 votos. Você olha outros usuários com certa atividade, e possuem negativadores muito mais contumazes, se o AP tem um perseguidor, então todo mundo têm, e teria que cancelar quase todos negativos dados no site.

Nos comentários tudo colocado é só especulação, não está havendo essa perseguição, não há dados que mostrem isso, pelo menos nos critérios adotados (só os 3 votos há indício). Se mudar o critério eu puno esse usuário, retiro esses votos e faço o mesmo com todos usuários que dá para ver que é perseguição até pior, eu me beneficiaria bastante. Metade dos negativos que recebi sumiriam. Só esses 3 votos tem clareza que foram por vingança. Eu tenho centenas de negativos mais claros que foram vingança.

Desde o início do site é assim: [Como será tratada uma "guerra de votos" ou "serial downvote" no br.SO?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/90/101) (nada mais foi feito a não ser reversão do sistema). Eu queria que fosse diferente. Eu queria que o site revertesse mais os votos dados dessa forma, eu queria que houvesse punição para casos assim, eu queria que os moderadores pudessem reverter negativos dados por vingança, mas não é assim que funciona. Se fosse assim eu já teria resolvido esse e outros casos. Lamento que eu não possa fazer como eu acho que deveria ser, até porque não teria tanta perseguição. Quando eu posso fazer algo o problema é resolvido. É o caso que contei antes, a pessoa parou de abandonar e criar novas contas quando pude fazer o que eu achava que devia fazer, e o problema foi resolvido.

Recentemente me posicionei contra a atitude da SE de deixar essas coisas rolarem, por isso estou começando a me importar menos com o site, só o mínimo burocrático necessário, o que será uma pena, mas a SE não ajuda, ela não quer que esses problemas sejam resolvidos, eles querem que dê trabalho. Eu sou punitivista, sempre deu mais resultado que garantismo.

Comment: é alguns pontos como: `Que esse é um caso muito pequeno para tomar uma providência` eu assim acho que tudo começa pelos pequenos problemas e vão crescendo, esses votos são mais claros em relação sequencia, dia, hora e minuto praticamente, e depois disso levei mais votos negativos principalmente na **tag** `javascript` que sim tem problemas de mau qualidade de perguntas, mas, que a gente consegue salvar algumas dessas perguntas, e os comentários são especulações: veja a gente não sabe quem votou, a gente está julgando comportamento, um mau comportamento inclusive então em alguns pontos ...

Comment: ... a sua resposta se alinha ao SE pela simples premissa que é assim e pronto, talvez nesse ponto Maniero os moderadores deveriam mudar também, são textos alinhados sempre ao SE (claro SE que manda ou ...) Veja estou fazendo o advogado do ... mas, aqui eu concordo quando você se irrita com o SE pela falta de ferramenta, pela falta de um editor melhor pela falta de boa qualidades na pergunta e nenhuma estratégia para resolver isso, mas, eu percebo que você é um andorinha sozinha, ninguém está nem ai, veja nenhum moderador além de você fala nada e isso não é especulação é realidade

Comment: ... todas as sinalizações (e não é só as minhas) são ignoradas sumariamente é incrível a falta de ferramenta e assim vai desanimando, desanimando e isso já está contaminando vários pessoas.

Comment: Sim, é isso, por mim tudo seria diferente, teria bem menos problemas, mais qualidade, mas eu não sou dono do site, se eu fizer oque eu quero eu deixaria de ser moderador em 3 dias. Quando há punição os problema desaparecem quase por completo e as pessoas que querem causar problema ou vão embora ou se ajustam. Acho que muita gente causa problema por saber que não será punido. Eu mesmo já fiz coisas erradas porque sabia que não seria punido. Mas sempre tem um limite, às vezes a pessoa passa dele e aí a punição vem.

Comment: `Sim, é isso, por mim tudo seria diferente, teria bem menos problemas, mais qualidade, mas eu não sou dono do site, se eu fizer oque eu quero eu deixaria de ser moderador em 3 dias.` aqui nesse ponto eu realmente fiquei curioso o que você como moderador poderia fazer para melhorar o andamento do site e que isso levaria a sua própria punição ...  Enfim os problemas desse site são muitos, infelizmente e eu não acho que é qualidade, mas, sim do SE que não nos permite melhorar.