# Votos negativos com um certo tipo de padrão?

Tags: debate, respostas, voto-contra

Venho nos últimos meses levando votos negativos em respostas sendo que a quantidade de votos negativos sempre é ***-1***, ou seja, existe sim um padrão de recebimento de votos negativos e sempre são resposta com `ReactJs` ou `Javascript` como `tag` principal.

Exemplos de três respostas (tem mais, como exemplo acredito mostrar o que anda acontecendo):

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/516621/54880
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/515529/54880
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506201/54880

Geralmente são perguntas que estão em aberto (*ou estavam a muito tempo*) e cabe uma resposta e sinceramente é desanimador ter esse tipo de perseguição.

Qual atitude devo tomar?

Comment: Obviamente eu não sei dizer se é perseguição ou não, mas se forem poucas vezes que isso aconteceu, provavelmente a resposta seria a mesma que o Maniero deu [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8395/100416) (que foi uma pergunta sua sobre o mesmo assunto)

Comment: @RafaelTavares desculpa mas, é perseguição sim, não tem lógica levar sempre o -1 todas as vezes e as respostas claramente estão corretas, se fosse algo aleatório tudo bem, agora é nítido a impressão sempre na mesma tag e sempre o -1, mas, tudo bem ...

Comment: Tou só a especular, mas pela natureza das perguntas que tem pouca qualidade, quem deu negativo deu pq não quer essas perguntas com respostas, por terem pouca qualidade ou por serem um pouco para o help desk

Comment: Acredito que em vez da pessoa negativar uma pergunta ou resposta, deveria estar disposta a contribuir. Mas contribuir de qual forma? Incluindo um comentário para que o autor melhorasse sua pergunta/resposta. Então, caso não houvesse a melhora com um certo tempo, poderia editar ou realmente, negativar. Tenho visto que não está sendo a política no Brasil a positivação de perguntas ou respostas, esta é minha impressão. Já editei pergunta e respostas de terceiros, tentando melhorá-las de alguma forma. @novic, vc pode pedir uma auditoria pra ver se é o mesmo usuário que está negativando, não pode?

Comment: Não sei @ClarckMaciel se tem essa possibilidade!

Comment: O problema de perseguição é um problema antigo e que não tem solução no SOpt (ou outro site da rede). A única solução, ao meu ver, pra resolver o problema, é mostrar quem votou negativo. Eu já fui vítima de perseguição uns tempos atrás, inclusive de um usuário que hoje é moderador.

Comment: @ClarckMaciel Vira e mexe o assunto volta, e as conclusões são as mesmas: a empresa responsável pelo site só quebra o sigilo do voto em casos "extremos" (vi uma vez no [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), mas no SOpt nunca vi), e ainda sim é de forma bem contida. Denunciar perseguição raramente é conclusivo. Quanto a comentar em vez de votar, já fiz muito, hoje faço menos mas ainda faço, mas é inefetivo (a maioria não aceita os comentários e/ou não melhora, alguns xingam e outros dão negativos de vingança) - é por isso que muita gente desanimou de comentar e só vota sem dizer nada...

Comment: ... Não é o ideal, mas infelizmente é assim. Eu ainda comento algumas vezes, mas é só uma pequena minoria que de fato consegue levar de forma construtiva e melhorar. Já teve gente que reclamou porque eu editei ("_por que não responde em vez de ficar editando?_"), esse tipo de coisa desanima com o tempo. Quanto a forma de votação atual, eu duvido muito que vá mudar, tem até um [FAQ gigante](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436) que explica os motivos (eu concordo em partes, de qq forma é interessante ler para entender porque é assim, e porque provavelmente não vai mudar)

Comment: Na minha opinião, o site deveria exigir que o usuário tenha feito um comentário na pergunta ou na resposta para liberar o registro de um voto negativo. Recebi ontem duas negativações em perguntas que, a meu ver estavam corretas e tinham utilidade, simplesmente recebi a negativação e não tenho idéia do que posso melhorar. A impressão que dá é que alguém só disse: "Não gostei do que você falou".

Na real, isso desanima. Você tira um pouco do seu tempo, que na maioria das vezes é escasso pra ajudar a comunidade, toma voto negativo sem saber a razão, e a moderação não pode fazer nada. respeito.

Comment: O indivíduo que vai em publicações geralmente simples e negativa a pergunta e todas as respostas, critica as respostas dadas e a pergunta, mas ainda sim não deixou uma dica, uma sugestão ou edição. De que forma esse indivíduo está contribuindo para a comunidade? sinto estar sofrendo perseguição já que TODAS as minhas respostas o mesmo sujeito vem e negativa, sempre apontando algo que as vezes é simplesmente uma falta de entendimento dele. creio que as perguntas simples deveriam ter uma área especial aqui, já que os membros antigos SEMPRE negativam as mesmas e todas suas respostas sem ajudar